# Selenium automation - ID is different when using ChromeDriver

Tags: html, selenium-chromedriver

Working with an in-house developed application, when I go to the web site manually (launch Chrome, type in the URL, etc.) and inspect a particular element, I see that element with the ID attribute as follows:

id="input-145"

When I use Chromedriver and Selenium to run my test, the same element shows up with this ID attribute:

id="input-147"

Has anyone ever seen this before? I'm not sure how to proceed.

I was expecting the ID attribute to remain the same regardless of how the site is accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some frameworks use dynamic id for input to protect against parsers. I solved this problem using element search by **full** xpath.

Example:

```
# xpath: does not work with dynamic id
input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='input-147']") 

# full xpath: work with dynamic id
input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/header/div/form/div/input")
```

[Locating by xpath documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)